# How can I switch to the right or left editor tab in SSMS using a shortcut?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have been using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) for a while now, but is there a way to switch to the right or left editor tab quickly using a keyboard shortcut? Currently, I have to use the mouse to switch between tabs, which can be a bit time-consuming.

What is the keyboard shortcut (if there is one) to switch between tabs in SSMS? Or is there another way to do this more efficiently?

Additionally, I have noticed that, when I have multiple tabs open, SSMS moves the editors around instead of switching to them (e.g., Click "Window" - "Windows", and double-click an entry), which can be a bit confusing. I would like to understand the logic behind this behavior, and if there's a way to switch between tabs without having the editors move around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into the Keyboard submenu in the options.
To move to the next, previous tab, the default shortcut is `Ctrl + PgDN` and `Ctrl + PgUp`, respectively

It can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

But when I was testing it, I had to press `Ctrl + Alt + PgDn` to make this work.